# Must contain a non-null value and possible null reference

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to switch to .Net 6.0 from .Net 3.1 and I encounter a few issues.

Apparently, in .Net 6.0 models need to have non-nullable property, for example:

```
public string Email { get; set; } = String.Empty;
```

The problem for the DbSet I fixed like:

```
public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }
```

However, now I'm getting warnings of possible null reference argument/return as the image below:

[image: possiblenull]

Comment: Your `GetUserByEmail` says it returns `User` (not nullable), yet is using `FirstOrDefault` which can return `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs [show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset)  you can use `Set` method with expression bodied property:

```cs
public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
```

Comment: I guess now the methods should have ? as well. Like:         
public User? GetUserByEmail(string email).

Comment: @William yes, to fully leverage nullable reference types you need to  mark API accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Models don't "need to have non-nullable properties". It's just a suggestion.

If this is not the behavior you want you can open csproj file and either remove this line or make it disable

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```